# NavStack Robot Moves Backwards

Tags: ros, navigation, velocity, move-base, 2d-nav-goal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Folks,

When my robot is trying to avoid an obstacle, it tends to move backwards. How can I disable that option so that the robot only have forward velocity, and rotational velocity?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203453/navstack-robot-moves-backwards/) by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 803 on 2015-02-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2015-02-19**:
What local planner are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need need to disable the escape velocity, which causes the robot to move backwards when stuck.

Just went inside:

```
base_local_planner_params.yaml
```

and added this parameter:

```
escape_vel: 0.0
```

---

Originally posted by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) with karma: 803 on 2015-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0